# DataContract inheritance not known type

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontract

Hi my datacontract has inheritance, but the last member is not accessible when consuming the service:

```
namespace Services.SearchService
{

    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(LabellingSearch))]
    public class SearchResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Specialist Search Result for Labelling Content Data
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(Labelling))]
    public class LabellingSearch : SearchResult
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Region { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public string LabelSummary { get; set; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Full Labelling Content Data
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    public class Labelling : LabellingSearch
    {
        public string Content { get; set; }
   }
}
```

so in the consuming class I can access the type 'Labelling' but I can't get at its 'Content' property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't put that member of the class as **[DataMember]**

```
[DataContract]
    public class Labelling : LabellingSearch
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Content { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to `Content` property because it's not `DataMember` so it's not serialized. Add `[DataMember]` attribute

```
[DataMember]
public string Content { get; set; }
```

From MSDN about **DataMemberAttribute Class**:

> When applied to the member of a type, specifies that the member is part of a data contract and is serializable by the DataContractSerializer.

Comment: Been staring at it too long and just couldn't see it